# Como manter a barra de rolagem de uma div sempre em baixo?

Tags: jquery, css

tenho uma div que se atualiza a cada 4 segundos e uso o overflow nela, preciso de que a barra de rolagem fique sempre alinhada na ultima linha . alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que precisas é dar ao scroll a altura da div, depois de atualizar o conteúdo. Algo como:

```
var height = el.scrollHeight;
el.scrollTop = height;
```

#### Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/xtxj6orp/1/

***Nota:*** No Firefox a altura da div que vai expandir tem de estar defenida, para o browser passar essa div para *modo visualização scroll*. Como no CSS do exemplo que coloquei.

#### Mais leitura:

- [Element.scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight)
- [Element.scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop)

Comment: nesse seu exemplo a barra de rolagem continua sempre em cima, porem eu precisava que ela acompanha-se os items abaixos que forem sendo criados

Comment: @ArsomNolasco para mim a barra está sempre em baixo... que Browser estás a usar?

Comment: mozzila firefox, e realmente no crhome esta em baixo, existe algum " gato pra funcionar no ff tambem? até achei isso que funcionou porem so no inicio que fica, depois se e adicionado outra linha permanece parado $(".messages").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "fast");
  return false;

Comment: @ArsomNolasco interessante. Acho que sei o que é, dá-me uns minutos.

Comment: @ArsomNolasco dá uma olhada aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/xtxj6orp/1/ tens de defenir a altura máxima do elemento que expande. Para ele passar a modo _scroll_ quando essa altura for alcançada.

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou certinho se tu puder editar a sua resposta inserindo esse detalhe para o mozila tambem agradeço pois ajudara outros com a mesma duvidas

Comment: @ArsomNolasco feito, obrigado.